# Component not loading when route changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I am using Preact. I first tried preact-router then wouter for routing, but the problem still exists for one specific component. Here is the main entry where all routes defined:

```
import { h, Component } from 'preact';
import { Route } from "wouter-preact";
import Header from './partials/header';

import Home from './pages/home';
import News from './pages/news';
import Article from './pages/article';

export default class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="app">
                <Header />
                <Route path="/"><Home /> </Route>  // working perfectly 
                <Route path="/a/:article">  <Article /> </Route>  // not working
                <Route path="/n/:newspaper"><News /> </Route>  // working
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and here is the simplified second component which is working perfectly :

```
import { h, Fragment } from 'preact';
import { Link, Route } from "wouter-preact";
import useFetch from '../../utils/ajax';



export default function News() {
    const url = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    const { data, loading } = useFetch(domain + '/api/v1/news/?newspaper=' + url[2]);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            {loading ? (
                // loading indicator
            ) : (
                <main role="main">
                    <div className="py-5">
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="row">

                                {data.results.map((nisha, index) => (
                                    <div className="col-sm-6" key={index}>
                                        <div className="col-md-10" >
                                            <div className="card mb-2 shadow-lg" style={{ border: 'none' }} >
                                                <Link href={'/a/' + nisha.slug}>
                                                    <img className="card-img-top" src={ nisha.cover_image } alt={ nisha.slug } />
                                                </Link>
                                                <div className="card-body">
// body
                                                    <div className="card-footer text-muted">
// footer

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                ))}

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
            )}
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

and finally the problematic component, when I click any link from previous component, browser url changing but the component is not loading (there is no debug console message in browser console).

```
export default function Article() {
    console.log("loaded");
    return (
        <div className="main">
            <div className="py-5">
                <div className="column">
                    <div>example article</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you re-order the components? I'm not familiar with wouter, but it could be that it's simply loading the last one.

Comment: I already tried this way with both router, nothing changed.

Comment: Not sure I can help much, but I'd suggest replacing the component - try rendering the same component as the one that is working. If that loads, you know the problem is the component. If it doesn't load, the problem's with the router. I can't see a particular problem with what you've done at a glance.

Comment: Wait a sec .. where is your Switch? https://codesandbox.io/s/0lr3n?file=/index.js has a working example.